# Uploading a URL-specified document to an array of bytes

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee, servlets, file-upload

I have an html-form with a field that will take a url pointing to a (possibly binary) file (e.g. an image). The url can point to a local resource that the server can't reach, so it needs to be fetched by the client. (This fetching is another point, my question is about writing the servlet.)

I want to upload the result of this fetch to a Java servlet (through a http POST request) and put it into an array of bytes. Since this is a low-level representation, I'm not sure if I should use Apache's FileUpload.

Another point that confused me, is that `FileItem`s in FileUpload only provide an `OutputStream` where I was expecting an `InputStream` to read the file.

I'm stuck after studying FileUpload. I may be that my basic knowledge of web-app development falls short.

How should I build this functionality? Please note that I'm new to this corner of Java development (although my general (i.e. SE) Java skills are very good).

Comment: To do what you want, the user will have to download the binary file, store it on his disk, and then use a file input to choose the location of the file on his disk, and upload the file. There is no way, AFAIK, to automatically transfer the content of a URL to the server. You could just post the URL, but then the server would have to reach the URL itself to download the image.

Comment: @JBNizet Actually my question was about writing the servlet. The front-end fetching is another (interesting) point I may post a question about. I updated my question to clarify it's about the servlet, not about the front-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep using FileUpload, don't reinvent it yourself. This will be a waste of time.

I'm not sure why you think that `FileItem` only provides an `OutputStream`, there's also an [`getInputStream()`](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html#getInputStream%28%29) method. Just write it to a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html).

```
InputStream input = fileItem.getInputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
IOUtils.copy(input, output);
byte[] bytes = output.toByteArray();
// ...
```

You only need to keep in mind that this may explode your server's memory usage if there are a lot of users uploading files at the same time. Each byte of a byte array eats one byte of JVM's memory. So imagine you've 100 simultaneous users who upload each a 10MB file, then 1GB of server memory is wasted to this.

Comment: You're absolutely right about `getInputStream`; I've just implemented it that way. Apparently I was sloppy. My question seems silly now. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you're just trying to receive a file uploaded over HTTP in a servlet? There are plenty of examples of how to do that on the net, e.g., http://www.servlets.com/jservlet2/examples/ch04/UploadTest.java

Am I just missing something in your question?

Comment: The point is getting it into an array of bytes. It's probably unwise to build something like that from scratch (if I want to implement RFC 1867), as there are good implementations available. My problem is that I don't understand how to get an array of bytes with (e.g.) Apache FileUpload. As said, since I'm not experienced in EE development it may be that I'm simply overlooking or misunderstanding something.

Comment: In the example I linked to you get the File object like this `File f = multi.getFile(name);` from there you can get an InputStream and read it in to a byte array.